# About Laravel - How to use function string in view

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-4, article

i try to to show data from database article...the content is contain html tags and long text..
so i want make a read more and convert tag html to html view..

this is my code is run :

> {{ HTML::decode($show->content) }}
>   {{ str_limit($show->content, $limit=100, $end=' ...') }}

i try this :

> {{ HTML::decode(str_limit($show->content,$limit=100, $end=' ...')) }}
>   {{ str_limit(HTML::decode($show->content),$limit=100, $end=' ...') }}

but not show ( blank )

annyone can help me to fix it??

thank u b4

Answer (score 0):

Is `{{ $show->content }}` returning any data to format?

Is your template is .blade?

Maybe it placed somewhere in HTML, where it is not visible?

Try to use this construction with some predefined string to find out if it works. Here is working example:

`{{ str_limit('Some big text', $limit = 5, $end='...') }}`

Comment: i use .blade template. {{ $show->content }} is show data, but too long..i wanna make a read more...
in database i have a data text like : <p>Lorem ipsum... </p>
i wanna make <p> convert to html view :)
any idea?
so i need str_limit+html::decode

Comment: I understood what you want.
What is returning without `HTML::decode()` (only `str_limit` on `$show->content`)?

Comment: Strip html tags and add them after str_limit if it needed.